# How can you pass data into an Angular 2 component with router.navigate()?

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a simple system where I have a login component, a login service, a info component (containing info about the user) and an info service.

The idea I have is to get the login component to send the usr/pwd to the login service and if it comes back with 'true' (i.e. valid credentials) the app swaps out the login component for the info component and populates it with that user's data (this being from `<router-outlet></router-outlet>`).

I'm changing the component by `this.router.navigate(["farmer"])` - how do I pass in a string containing the name of the farmer too? (this will be the username they log in with).

Answer (score 0):

I would have a singleton global service and set the name in there, it would then be accessible wherever you accessed that service.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to add route info/:name, and when you invokes .navigate() method from login component, just pass an additional object of type NavigationExtras. 
It would be something like this:

```
this.router.navigate(['/info'], { queryParams: { name: 'farmer' } });
```

Comment: Is it possible to do this without using /:pathvars - would it be possible to read the queryparams from the router object?